# How to display Modalpopuextender, target control in Datalist?

Tags: asp.net

In web application, I place modal popu extender, problem is taraget control  is in datalist control, how can i write the targetcontrolid. when i click the button which is in datalist i want to show the modal popup control. Can you help me.

```
 protected void dtlstMagazine_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
 {
     ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
 }
```

Thank you for replay. I solve this problem

Comment: I sove this problem my self. i write the code in datalist row command event like

Comment: i am placing the code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving an Idea, I didn't tested this, try this Out

1. Place a Link/Image button (based on your requirement) inside a
   DataList control and assign ItemCommand event for that
2. Place a ModelPopupExtender outside a Datalist
3. Place a Button (say ID="BtnPopup") tag with style="display:none" next to
   ModelPopupExtender
4. Give Target controle ID as "BtnPopup" (Dummy button) to ModelPopupExtender
5. Place your content to be displayed as Popup in Update panel, looks like this

   ```
   <asp:Panel.....>
     <asp:Button ....> <!-- your popup close button, Outside update panel -->
     <asp:UpdatePanel......>
       <!-- your Content to be displayed as popup !-->
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
   </asp:Panel>
   ```
6. Now on Datalist ItemCommand event, show the Popup as follows
   ModelPopExtenderID.show();

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this...

Keep a hidden button like this

```
<asp:Button ID="hiddenPopupTarget" runat="server" Style="display: none;"/>
```

And set the `TargetcontrolID` of the `modalpopupextender` to `hiddenPopupTarget`.

Now, in the linkbutton click event show the modalpopupextender using `ModalPopupExtender1.Show();`